# What's the difference between Grails mongodb plugin v1.3.3 and v2.0.1? Many people seem to use v1.3.3

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

I see many Grails applications using version 1.3.3. Will upgrading our Grails 2.3.11 application to use mongodb-2.0.1 cause any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see what changed between versions I suggest you look at the [change log](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin%3achangelog-panel) for the plugin.

Typically plugins which have issue trackers (on the plugin portal page for the plugin) have some type of change log within them.

Comment: So is 2.0.1 necessarily a better version than 1.3.3?

Comment: I can't answer a broad question as to if it's "better" since it's not my requirements that need to be met by the plugin. You need to evaluate that for yourself, against your requirements of the plugin. Does 2.0.1 Fix bugs you have issues with? Does it have new features you need? That's the kind of question you need to ask yourself.

Comment: Yes, that's what it would include. It may also include incompatibilities, breaking changes, and other side-effects.

Comment: Yeah that's right. I wondered if they are separate streams just like Python 2 and 3.